# Skipping native extension recompilation on subsequent bundle install

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler, nokogiri

My production deployments take a few extra minutes due to time it takes to install nokogiri gem (1.6.0). I understand this is because installing the gem triggers native extension compilation.

Note that I have packaged my bundle and checked it into DVCS

```
bundle package
```

Is there a way to avoid recompilation of native extensions if nothing else has changed, so that deployments are faster?

**Update:**

I use Opscode Chef to deploy (chef-solo to be specific)

environment is:
Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit
Ruby 193-p448

Comment: A `bundle install` usually skips gems that Bundler finds already matching requirements. What are you using to deploy?

Comment: @NeilSlater I use chef to deploy.

Comment: I don't have an answer for all native extensions, but did you try adding `NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=true`?

Comment: @zrl3dx No I have not tried this option. Will give it a try for the sake of learning. However, I found generic way to solve the issue, which I have posted below as an answer.

Comment: @zrl3dx I tried learning more about NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=true. I think this **does** save significant amount of disk space but **does not** significantly reduce the time required to install nokogiri gem. Also, It makes the gem `non portable` since it is now dynamically linked. Thanks for the tip though. Will surely have a use case to use this in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to do this. Here is the explanation:

Bundler, by default installs gems into a folder pointed by the environment variable `BUNDLE_PATH`. The default value of `BUNDLE_PATH` is `vendor/bundle`. Hence all gems are installed in `/vendor/bundle` folder, which happens to be a private folder (for each version of the Rails application). When a new version of the Rails application is installed, `vendor/bundle` does not exist. Hence Bundler installs/precompiles each gem. It picks up the gems from `vendor/cache` which is a good saving over downloading the same from `rubygems.org`, but it still cannot avoid compilation of native extensions.

We can override this by passing `--path /shared/path` to the `bundle install` command line. This will ensure that the gems are always installed in `/shared/path`, which is accessible to all versions (of the Rails application).

With this approach, bundler will not try to reinstall/recompile a gem, since it finds the same already installed.

so, this is the magic command that worked for me

```
bundle install --local --deployment --path /shared/bundle --without development test
```

Comment: Be wary that one day, you might have an app stuck in the past that cannot use the most recent gem. When that occurs, you might sorely regret to not have vendored your gems.

Comment: Not true. In production, I want the app to use only the gems that are locked with `Gemfile.lock`. Gem upgrades happen in development (using `bundle outdated` and `bundle update`). Since I use `bundle package`, those upgraded gems are stored in `vendor/cache`. And in production when I run `bundle install --deployment` the new gems are picked up from `vendor/cache` and installed in the path specified by `--path` option as explained above.

Comment: This is so useful and perfectly safe that I wonder why this is not the default behaviour when using `--deployment` ! Nokogiri is every deployer's worst nightmare.